# Call to a member function loadXML() on a non-object (PHP - PayPal)

Tags: php, dom, xml-parsing, paypal-adaptive-payments

I finally managed to get an PaymentDetailResponse from PayPal, which looks like this:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <ns2:PaymentDetailsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap">
    <responseEnvelope>
    <timestamp>2013-11-27T16:54:16.964-08:00</timestamp>
    <ack>Success</ack>
    <correlationId>bb7958693354</correlationId>
    <build>7935900</build>
    </responseEnvelope>
    <cancelUrl>https://www.paypal.com</cancelUrl>
    <currencyCode>EUR</currencyCode>
    <paymentInfoList>
    <paymentInfo>
.
.
.
    <useCredentials>true</useCredentials></sender>
    </ns2:PaymentDetailsResponse><br />
```

I'm using the following function:

```
function verify_paypal($payKey, $appID)
{
  global $payPalUser_Id, $payPalPassword, $payPalSig;
$headerArray = array(
'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID:'.$payPalUser_Id,
'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD:'.$payPalPassword,
'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE:'.$payPalSig,
'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID:'.$appID,
'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT:NV',
'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT:XML'
);

$url="https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails?payKey={$payKey}&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headerArray);

$adaptiveResponse = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if (!is_null($adaptiveResponse)){
  echo $adaptiveResponse;
  //check result
  $dom_document->loadXML($adaptiveResponse);
  $searchNode = $dom_document->getElementsByTagName("ack"); 

  if (!is_null($searchNode)) {
    $value=$Node->nodeValue;
    if (strtolower($value) =="failure"){
      return false;
    }
}
```

But on loadXML($adaptiveResponse); I get the following error:

```
Call to a member function loadXML() on a non-object
```

I don't see any reason why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't initialize ([Manual](https://www.php.net/domdocument.loadxml))

```
$dom_document = new DOMDocument();
```

It should be initialized first and then use

```
$dom_document->loadXML($adaptiveResponse);
```

Comment: thanks, it can be so easy sometimes.. And Google not always helpful!

Comment: @Diego, Welcome! It happens :-)